# NSPredicate on nested array with NSDictionary as object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

i have a NSDictionary like:

```
{
"2017-05-02" =     (
            {
        "always_valid" = 0;
        date = "2017-05-02";
        from = "12:00";
        to = "13:00";
    },
            {
        "always_valid" = 0;
        date = "2017-05-02";
        from = "12:00";
        to = "12:00";
    },
            {
        "always_valid" = 0;
        date = "2017-05-02";
        from = "14:00";
        "hourly_rate" = 12;
        to = "15:00";
    }
);
"2017-05-03" =     (
            {
        "always_valid" = 0;
        date = "2017-05-03";
        from = "12:00";
        to = "13:00";
    }
);
"2017-05-18" =     (
            {
        "always_valid" = 1;
        date = "2017-05-18";
        from = "12:00";
        to = "12:00";
    }
);
}
```

i'm trying to apply

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"always_valid = \"1\""];
 NSArray *alwaysvalid = [[dic allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

it use to work when i had structure something like

array > dictionary

but now it's like

array > array > dictionary

by doing [dic allValues] for array.
any help what should i apply to keep it fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is need enumerate your dictionary and create new filtered Dictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *filterDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"always_valid = 1"];
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* key, NSArray* obj, BOOL *stop) {
     NSArray *filterArray = [obj filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
     if (filterArray.count > 0) {
         filterDic[key] = filterArray;
     }
}];
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'

Comment: from  NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY always_valid = 1"];
NSArray *alwaysvalid = [[dic allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];

Comment: and "always_valid" will always be 1 or 0.

Comment: @SameerAzeem Have you tried using `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock` ?

Comment: @SameerAzeem I don't get it because if you dictionary contains all value as array this should work perfectly

Comment: i'm working with the same input i posted in the question

Comment: @SameerAzeem My mistake you cannot use Any you need to use `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock` and then filter array of it check the edited answer

Comment: i tried to do something like this with block predicate but stoped because it would have return the parent array.thanks for the new information :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
 NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dict];   // you can also do same for Name key... 
 NSArray *alwaysvalid = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

Comment: i should return "2017-05-18" =     (
            {
        "always_valid" = 1;
        date = "2017-05-18";
        from = "12:00";
        to = "12:00";
    }
);